# calling a c# function from javascript dosent work

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I'm buildung a WebApplication in asp.net with c# and i have a problem to call a c# function from the JS.

My code is like this:

**in js:**

```
Function doStuff()
{
    var service = new seatService.Service1();
    service.DoWork(id, onSuccess, null, null);
}
```

and in the service page is:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "seatService")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1 
{
    [OperationContract]
    public static  void DoWork(string id)
    {
      //here there is a function that calls the DB
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that one of 20 times it actually works (with the same code) but most of the time it fails and I get the message:

> uncaught referenceEror - seatService is not defined.

and the status code is `500 Internal Server Error.`

Since it sometime working and sometime doesn't - where is my problem?

Comment: There isn't enough information in the error you provide. Error 500 could be many options. You need to debug your page using developer tools and capture the response body that comes from the server using network capture, there you will see a clearer error info. See here example how to do it in Internet explorer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `Function` in your JavaScript code should be `function` (lowercase)

Comment: I did that but when i look for the response body it says that there is no data to show. the response header is:Key Value
Response HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date Sat, 09 Mar 2013 22:50:06 GMT
X-AspNet-Version 4.0.30319
Cache-Control private
Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length 9527
Connection Close

Comment: It is in lowercase. It starts with capital f only here by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `PageMethods` for this. Here's some sample code to demonstrate:

```
public partial class ContactUs : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   [WebMethod]
   public static void SendForm(string name, string email, string message)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
           throw new Exception("You must supply a name.");    
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
           throw new Exception("You must supply an email address.");   
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
           throw new Exception("Please provide a message to send.");

       //call your web service here, or do whatever you wanted to do
   }
}
```

From JavaScript:

```
SendForm = function() {
   var name = $get("NameTextBox").value;
   var email = $get("EmailTextBox").value;
   var message = $get("MessageTextBox").value;

   PageMethods.SendForm(name, email, message, OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
}    
OnSucceeded = function() {
   $get("ContactFieldset").innerHTML = "<p>Thank you!</p>";
}    
OnFailed = function(error) {
   alert(error.get_message());
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but i got the message: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'PageMethods' is undefined"... the class ContactUs is a the c# class of asp that runs the js or it is the Service class?

Comment: Ok. it works. i added the EnablePageMethods="true" in the scriptManager in the asp page. thanks for the help!